# Maintain same tableviewcell height in different phone size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a table view which contains the setting that looks like current iPhone setting page.

I want the tableview to remain the same size as well as for the image icon for each setting. Much like in iPhone 5 and iPhone 6, even though iPhone 6 is much bigger but the icon size remains the same as iPhone 5.

I've added iPhone 6 and 6+ launch screen and for the image icon, i've set constraint for height as well as aspect ratio. In code, i didn't declare heightForRow and in storyboard, i leave height for tableview cell as default.

Is everything i did correct? or am i missing something? i'm doing the storyboard in wAny hAny size class.

Comment: The default height for UITableView is 44 Pixels which remain constant on all devices when we add UITableView to a view. It does not change under or unless you do so.

Comment: You want the cell height to increase according to screen?

Comment: @Mr.UB nope..i want it to remain the same...just like in my question mention, i want the setting screen size to be the same in iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 (meaning the image icon doesn't get scaled up). 

If u have both iPhone 5 and iPhone 6, look at the setting...the icon size in setting is the same for both, just that iPhone 6 can view much more tableview cell than iPhone 5. thats what i'm trying to achieve and i'm not sure if the method i mention above is correct or am i still missing something

Comment: It will work that way by default unless you have set sizes for both devices, can you share screenshots of setting screen for both 5&6 devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not change the value you have put for the height of the table view cell, will remain fixed for all devices.

See the image for details.

[image: In Row Height you can put a fixed value]